# MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: spring, jackson

I am trying to upgrade Spring Application (not using Spring Boot) from 2.3.2.RELEASE to 5.3.20 (latest version as of today), I do see below code is breaking and

Code:

```
@Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();

        ObjectMapper defaultMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        defaultMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
        defaultMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.REQUIRE_SETTERS_FOR_GETTERS, true);
        mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(defaultMapper);

        converters.add(mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter);
    }
```

What's the replacement of import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper to jacksondata bind for below code?

```
ObjectMapper defaultMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        defaultMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
        defaultMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.REQUIRE_SETTERS_FOR_GETTERS, true);
        mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(defaultMapper);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do like below

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper objectMapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.REQUIRE_SETTERS_FOR_GETTERS, true);
mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.html) is for Jackson1, which isn't supported anymore with Spring 5, it was deprecated in Spring 4.

You will need to migrate to Jackson2 and use the [`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html) instead.

Instead of constructing the `ObjectMapper` manually I strongly suggest using the [`Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.html) to construct the `ObjectMapper`. It will automatically detect and register well known Modules and allows for easier configuration.

```java
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
      .defaultViewInclusion(true)
      .featuresToEnable(SerializationConfig.Feature.REQUIRE_SETTERS_FOR_GETTERS)
      .build(); 

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = 
        new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
    converters.add(converter);
}
```

Finally use the constructor instead of the setter as that saves building an additional `ObjectMapper` (done in the default constructor of the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and then throwing it away) saves a few CPU cycles.